# how to force avro writer to write timestamp in UTC in spark scala dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro, spark-avro

I need to write Timestamp field to avro and ensure the data is saved in UTC. currently avro converts it to long (timestamp millis ) in the Local timezone of the server  which is causing issues as if the server reading bk is a different timezone. I looked at the DataFrameWriter it seem to mention an option called timeZone but it doesnt seem to help.Is there  a way to force Avro to consider all timestamp fields received in a specific timezone?

```
**CODE SNIPPET** 
--write to spark avro

val data = Seq(Row("1",java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2020-05-11 15:17:57.188")))
val schemaOrig = List( StructField("rowkey",StringType,true)
,StructField("txn_ts",TimestampType,true))
val sourceDf =  spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),StructType(schemaOrig))
sourceDf.write.option("timeZone","UTC").avro("/test4")

--now try to read back from avro
spark.read.avro("/test4").show(false)
avroDf.show(false)

original value in soure 2020-05-11 15:17:57.188
in avro  1589224677188
read bk from avro wt out format 
+-------------+-------------+
|rowkey       |txn_ts       |
+-------------+-------------+
|1            |1589224677188|
+-------------+-------------+

This is mapping fine but issue is if the local time of the server writing is EST and the one reading back is GMT it would give problem . 

println(new java.sql.Timestamp(1589224677188L))
2020-05-11 7:17:57.188   -- time in GMT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.option("timeZone","UTC")` option will not convert timestamp to UTC timezone.

Set this `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")` config property to set UTC as default timezone for all timestamps.

By defaul value for `spark.sql.session.timeZone` property is JVM system local time zone if not set.

Incase If above options are not working due to lower version of spark try using below options.

`--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone=UTC" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone=UTC"`